# Multiple approval workflow by sharepoint 2010 foundation

Tags: designer-workflow

I have created custom approval workflow on sharepoint2010 foundation designer, I used "Collect Data from a user" action property but it is not allowing me to start workflow automatically, it's through below error "you can not use task action in this workflow because iw will start another instance of the same workflow.........."

I want to add two approvers and start workflow automatically.
If somebody have any idea please help me.
Thanks